# array.resize двумерный массив расширить

Tags: c#, массивы

```
private string person = new string[10, 2];

person =  Array.Resize(ref [,] person, 11, 2); //здесь ошибка
```

не могу понять как работать с двумерным массивом используя Array.Resize().
по заданию нельзя использовать что либо другое кроме массивов

Comment: Метода с такой сигнатурой не существует в BCL, поэтому штатными средствами это невозможно.

Comment: array.copy() можно применить ?

Comment: Можно, но это не решит вашу задачу.

Comment: так сделайте resize вручную - создайте новый массив другого размера и заполните его данными из начального массива

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.array.resize Ну, очевидно, что метод предназначенный для изменения одномерного массива у вас не сработал. Там же ниже есть пример для ресайза многомерного массива.

Comment: Используйте [jagged array](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) - _изрезанный массив_ - `string[][]`. В этом варианте можно ресайзить как сам _внешний_ массив, так и внутренние (не одним вызовом, придется использовать цикл).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воплотим в реальность комментарий про "изрезанный массив". Напишите пользовательский класс, подобный этому:

```
class MyString
{
    private string[][] person;

    public MyString(string[][] _person)
    {
        if (_person == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("_person");
        person = _person;
    }

    public void Resize(int i, int j)
    {
        var per = new string[i][];
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)
        {
            per[k] = new string[j];
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < person.Length; k++)
        {
            for (int l = 0; l < person[k].Length; l++)
            {
                per[k][l] = person[k][l];
            }
        }

        person = per;
    }

    public void Display()
    {
        foreach (var str in person)
        {
            foreach (var s in str)
            {
                Console.Write(s + '\t');
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Если нельзя использовать классы, можете метод Resize модернизировать вот до такой степени:

```
static void ArrayResize(int i, int j, ref string[][] array)
{
    var arr  = new string[i][];
    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)
    {
        arr[k] = new string[j];
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < array.Length; k++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < array[k].Length; l++)
        {
            arr[k][l] = array[k][l];
        }
    }
    array = arr;
}
```

Comment: я так понимаю, у вас `Resize` только в большую сторону? Иначе вот тут упадет `per[k][l] = person[k][l];`

Comment: по сути да, можно и это предусмотреть